# Lint tool for actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, code-analysis, lint

Are there any lint tools available for actionscript?  One source would be ideal, but anything is welcome.

My team is starting to adopt more a more rigorous style guide (where "more rigorous" means "existant"), and I think a linter would help us all adhere more easily to the style rules we've agreed on.  I'm not above writing my own, but I'd like to see what else is out there first.

A quick search on Google reveals nothing (at least so far).

Comment: Is it time to ask the question again?

Comment: Any updates on available AS lint tools since Jan 2009?

Answer (score 10):

If you're dealing with Flex, take a look at [FlexPMD](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD).

Comment: I haven't evaluated FlexPMD personally, but if it works even close to as well as its Java counterpart, this is the way to go!

Comment: This project appears to have died around 2010.

Answer (score 4):

FlexPMD should actually be named As3PMD. I mean you can run FlexPMD against a pure AS3 project, not necessarly a Flex project.

That said there are around 10 rules which are Flex-specific.

Xavier

Answer (score 2):

It's not Lint, but I've found the free FlashDevelop to make me write better code, as it complains about many possible problems, such as undeclared variables.

http://www.flashdevelop.org

You could check it out.

Then there's also flex builder that you can use to write AS.

Comment: Strictly, it's not FlashDevelop that does this but rather the mxmlc compiler that comes with the flex sdk. So any IDE coupled with that compiler will give you the same benefits. But FlashDevelop is still a great software!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite Lint, though Adobe's Flex `mxmlc` compiler gives plenty of helpful strict warnings about messy ActionScript, such as undeclared variables, missing function return types, and extra commas in an object/hash.

`mxmlc` resources:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_15.html#153435
- http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withmxmlc/

Some related code analysis tools are [Yasca](http://www.yasca.org/) (analysis tool for JavaScript, Java, PHP, etc.) and [asDox](http://code.google.com/p/asdox/) (AS3 parser written in Python), which might be decent starts for writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) in the past for jscript.  As is written in JavaScript and the full source code is available, so you should be able to get it working with actionscript.  I have not used any of the other tools mentions in the answers, so I don't know how they compare.

(jslint takes a very strong view about what is good jscript, you may or may not agree with it.)

Comment: This seems like a really tricky way of doing it… ActionScript is really quite different from JavaScript.

Comment: Actionscript is based on the same ECMAScript. The differences are that javascript should/is a prototypical language while actionscript wanted to be a more object oriented language.

Answer (score -2):

Actionscript 2.0 and 3.0 are ECMA compliant scripting languages.  Since ECMA script is essentially Javascript, you can typically use something like [JSure](http://aurochs.fr/jsure.html) (appears to be Linux only) or [Javascript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/).

Comment: The ECMAScript used in what we know as Javascript today doesn't have a lot to do with either ActionScript 2 or ActionScript 3.

Comment: Yea, sorry, ActionScript is sufficiently different from JavaScript that JavaScript tools rarely work.