# Flex lint (ie, style checker)?

Tags: apache-flex, lint

I remember reading about a lint-like tool for Flex code… But I'm having no luck finding it on Google. Can someone point me towards it?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412345/lint-tool-for-actionscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412345/lint-tool-for-actionscript)