# Is there a way to test ActionScript without having Flash installed?

Tags: actionscript

Is there a way to test Flash ActionScript scripts without having Flash installed and running them inside a swf?

Comment: Why don't you have flash installed?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? Graphics? Sound? Syntax?

Comment: syntax, and simple things like: function add(a, b){return a+b;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend flash develop. It works with flex sdk. it actually runs more smoother too. Not only this but it makes a far better IDE then flash cs4. it has a far better intellisense, and it also does intellisense for customs class. I have flash cs4 and I still use flashdevelop

Answer (score 2):

You could download the [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/flex) for free and use that, or
use the [Flex Module for Apache and IIS](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_Module_for_Apache_and_IIS), if you need to check scripts online.
I'm guessing it's what sites like [Wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/) use.

Otherwise, for simple things like

> function add(a, b){return a+b;}

You might as well adjust [lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/) or find [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412345/lint-tool-for-actionscript).

Answer (score 1):

While this may be a technicality, you could run actionscript code in the Adobe AIR runtime, as opposed to the Flash Player.  Deep down, though, there's still a swf involved in the creation of your AIR app.